# Retrieve text within multiple brackets in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
str = 'Concat(((("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ), ("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" )) ))'
```

I get the contents within concat function as

```
((("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ), ("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" )) )
```

Now I want to remove the round brackets present in str and output should be

```
"function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" , "function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME"
```

This is what I have tried:

```
res= str.strip().replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

Is there any better approach I can follow to get the required output. Please help

Comment: Does your approach work? If so, this is more of a code review question.

Comment: You could try using RE, https://regexr.com/

Comment: @M-Chen-3 It works. But not sure its the appropraite for all scenarios

Comment: @Evgeny Can you pleae help with my scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for regular expressions!

Mine is ugly but it works:

```
import re

# I changed this a bit for testing, but the spirit is the same.
s = '''((("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ), ("function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."something else" )) )'''
pat = r'\(([^\(\)]+)\)'
s_list = re.findall(pat, s)
```

Which returns:

```
 ['"function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."CATEGORY_NAME" ','"function_test"."PRODUCT_CATEGORIES"."something else" ']
```

If you want a string instead of a list, you can add:

```
 ','.join(s_list)
```

Comment: The pat is just a regular expression. I learned using [RegExOne](https://regexone.com/).

Comment: Thanku..will it work for any no  ( of brackets

Comment: I wanted a result as string and not list

Comment: Your question wasn't clear that you wanted a string. Regardless, I updated the answer.

Comment: @shee yes this works with any number of brackets and even unmatched brackets. It's worth understand how regular expressions work because they are very useful for this type of problem.